# Can I use code to change the color of my MacBook Pro keyboard backlight?

Tags: mac, terminal, backlight

I would like to have the colors of my Macbook's keyboard backlight change either permanently or on a cycle. If this can be done in terminal, let me know. I don't want to at all ever open my computer.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding what you're asking, because I'm not sure how on earth you could see what's on the screen properly if you're messing with the backlight on the display...

Comment: Could you please be more specific. Which model Mac? Are you referring to the actual backlight of the screen, keyboard or the Apple logo? Although as far as I am aware the colour of the lighting can't be changed as it is hardware controlled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the color of your display or keyboard backlight is impossible to do programatically, unless the manufacturer designed it with that capability to change color and to do so using software controllers.

It is highly likely that this is not the case, as it is not common except in very specific circumstances (for instance, the backlight on my old Nokia phone's keypad could do this, and I have an external USB keyboard that has different colored backlight options, but cannot change them programatically). If you want to change the color of the backlight and this path is not already available to you, you will have to open the computer up and swap out the light(s) yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering, some guys in my health class thought it would be cool, and I wondered if Macs had the capability to do so.

Comment: Not to mention unless it had a RGB Led array, its physically impossible. There *is* one keyboard on thinkgeek that allows this i think

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to change the back-light color, or even just the actual color, of the keyboard, you could try a colored Mac keyboard cover.

Here's a couple of websites to get you started:

https://Kbcovers.com/all-colors-keyboard-cover/

https://www.etsy.com/market/macbook_keyboard_color

Comment: Thanks to the moderator for the edit. it don't matter to me. but at least I gave a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is nothing controlling the color of the light. It's just an array of LEDs turned on to light up the keyboard.

To change the color, you will need to use a color filter to filter the light with a color.